# Detect BitLocker programmatically from Rust without admin privileges

Tags: windows, rust, bitlocker

similar to this thread:

[Detect BitLocker programmatically from c# without admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308245/detect-bitlocker-programmatically-from-c-sharp-without-admin/41310139#41310139)

I want to get the bitlocker status of a drive programmatically in Rust (without admin privileges).
Is there a way, to check the bitlocker status without admin privileges, similar to the thread above?
My goal is a function like:

```rust
use std::io;

// drive_letter could be something like "C"
fn is_bde_active(drive_letter: String) -> io::Result<bool> {
    [...]

}
```

I'm not very familiar with winapi or windows unfortunately. I have not found any IShellProperty in the [winapi documentation](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/).

Comment: I can't give an answer, but perhaps Microsoft's actively maintained [`windows-rs`](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) might be of help here. There seems (?) to be something in there, such as [`SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/bindings/windows/win32/windows_properties_system/fn.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName.html) and [`BitLockerEnabled`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/bindings/windows/win32/windows_clustering/constant.BitLockerEnabled.html) that might be of help. There is a "Getting started" video in their repository.