# There is a way to check bitlocker status on a drive without admin privileges?

Tags: python, bitlocker

I'm coding a python app which check the bitlocker status on a drive. I'm unsing subprocess to run commands lines in python. But i would like to use this app on computer without admin privileges but the command manage-bde only works with admin privileges. Can someone help me? 
PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: hm, have you tried powershell ?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work without admin

Comment: Try these maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows - hope something will suit your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if drive is BitLocker encrypted without admin privilege?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841973/how-to-tell-if-drive-is-bitlocker-encrypted-without-admin-privilege)